# error[E0277]: can't compare `str` with `&str`—what's the right way to do that?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to compare a slice of a slice of a string with a `&'static str`:

```
impl Tag for BoldTag {
    fn is_this_tag(text_slice: &str) -> bool {
        text_slice.len() >= 2 && text_slice[0..=1] == "**"
    }
}
```

That gives me the following error message:

```
error[E0277]: can't compare `str` with `&str`
   --> src/lib.rs:52:52
    |
 52 |         text_slice.len() >= 2 && text_slice[0..=1] == "**"
    |                                                    ^^ no implementation for `str == &str`
    |
    = help: the trait `PartialEq<&str>` is not implemented for `str`
    = help: the following other types implement trait `PartialEq<Rhs>`:
              <&'a str as PartialEq<OsString>>
              <&'a str as PartialEq<String>>
              <&'b str as PartialEq<Cow<'a, str>>>
              <String as PartialEq<&'a str>>
              <String as PartialEq<Cow<'a, str>>>
              <String as PartialEq<str>>
              <String as PartialEq>
              <str as PartialEq<Cow<'a, str>>>
            and 4 others
```

I understand that it's not possible to compare `str` and `&str`, but I don't quite understand how a slice of a `&str` becomes a `str` (and not `&&str`), nor what the right way to write this function is.

The explanation given by `rustc --explain E0277` is a generic, "You tried to use a type which doesn't implement some trait in a place which expected that trait," which doesn't really tell me how to fix this specific problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a `&` before slicing the string

```rust
fn is_this_tag(text_slice: &str) -> bool {
    text_slice.len() >= 2 && &text_slice[0..=1] == "**"
}
```

now you are comparing `&str` and `&str`